# XSL template having problems with closing tags

Tags: xml, xslt

The XSL style below generates empty values with a self closing tag. 
I need the empty tags to always generate a regular closing tag, like in html

I tried to change the xsl:output method to html. No success.

wrong: < tag / >

i want: < tag > < / tag >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="{{encoding}}" cdata-section-elements="{{cdata_section_elements}}" />
<xsl:param name="country"/>
<xsl:param name="language"/>
<xsl:param name="locale"/>
<xsl:param name="time"/>
<xsl:param name="date"/>
<xsl:param name="date_time"/>
<xsl:param name="currency"/>
<xsl:param name="file_url"/>

<xsl:template name="media_gallery">
    <xsl:param name="element_name" />    
    <xsl:for-each select="multi_attributes">
        <xsl:for-each select="media_gallery/image">                                              
            <xsl:element name="{$element_name}"><xsl:value-of select="value"/></xsl:element>                                                            
        </xsl:for-each>                                                 
    </xsl:for-each>                                 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="basic_attributes">
    <xsl:for-each select="attributes">                                      
        <xsl:for-each select="*">                                                
            <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>                                                            
        </xsl:for-each>                         
    </xsl:for-each>                                 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="categories">
    <xsl:param name="element_name" />    
    <xsl:for-each select="multi_attributes">
        <xsl:for-each select="categories/category">                                              
            <xsl:element name="{$element_name}"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:element>                                                         
        </xsl:for-each>                                                 
    </xsl:for-each>                                 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="copy">       
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>                                     
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="custom_attributes">
    <xsl:for-each select="custom_attributes/attribute">
        <xsl:element name="{tag}"><xsl:value-of select="value"/></xsl:element>                          
    </xsl:for-each>                             
</xsl:template>


<xsl:variable name="mainTag"><xsl:text>products</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="itemTag"><xsl:text>product</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:element name="{$mainTag}">
        <xsl:for-each select="/items/item">
            <xsl:for-each select="parent|child">
                    <xsl:element name="{$itemTag}">
                        <xsl:call-template name="basic_attributes"/>    
                        <xsl:call-template name="custom_attributes"/>                   
                    </xsl:element>                  
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:element>          
</xsl:template>

<nscdoc>
    <common>
        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>                                                              
        <decimal_delimiter>.</decimal_delimiter>
        <price_format>standard</price_format>
        <datetime_format>standard</datetime_format>
        <category_path_delimiter> > </category_path_delimiter>  
        <link_to_specification>http://www.kieskeurig.nl/document/B9A4D86D505D49709F9319BADC54D987</link_to_specification>           
        <allow_custom_attributes>1</allow_custom_attributes>
        <stock>
            <yes>1</yes>
            <no>0</no>
            <availability></availability>
        </stock>        
    </common>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <code>id</code>             
            <magento>id</magento>               
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>productgroep</code>               
            <magento>category_path</magento>                
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>merk</code>               
            <magento>manufacturer</magento>             
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>type</code>               
            <magento>model</magento>                
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>toevoeging-type</code>                
            <magento></magento>             
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>extra-productbeschrijving</code>              
            <magento>short_description</magento>    
            <postproc>cdata</postproc>          
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>partnumber</code>             
            <magento>sku</magento>              
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>ean-code</code>               
            <magento>ean</magento>              
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>prijs</code>              
            <magento>price_final_include_tax</magento>              
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>verzendkosten</code>              
            <magento>shipping_method_price</magento>                
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>afhaalkosten</code>               
            <magento></magento>             
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>levertijd</code>              
            <magento>delivery_time</magento>                
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>deeplink</code>               
            <magento>url</magento>              
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>imagelink</code>              
            <magento>image</magento>                
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <code>voorraad</code>               
            <magento>stock_status</magento>             
        </attribute>            
    </attributes>
</nscdoc>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Did you check this question [Self closing tags in xsl method: xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305190/self-closing-tags-in-xsl-method-xml). I'm sure you can make it work using that answer.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, haven't noticed that post. Just tried both options.. 

edit: worked ! I mislooked, the firefox xml tree will always render self closing tags. Source-code now also correct.