# Remove extra space between two lines

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I have following XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dso="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult"
exclude-result-prefixes="dso">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:for-each select="dso:FMPDSORESULT/dso:ROW">
        <record>
            <First_Name><xsl:value-of select="dso:First_Name"/></First_Name>
            <Last_Name><xsl:value-of select="dso:Last_Name"/></Last_Name>
            <Address><xsl:value-of select="dso:Address"/></Address>               
        </record>
    </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produced following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<record>

  <First_Name>John</First_Name>

  <Last_Name>Thomas</Last_Name>

  <Address>Stuttgart</Address>

</record>

<record>

  <First_Name>Aanshi</First_Name>

  <Last_Name/>

 <Address>Stuttgart</Address>
```

Here If data is not available then its showing only closing tag.Is there any way to show null value between opening and closing tag.I want to something like this

```
<Address></Address>
```

Also,how to remove space between two line?

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
  <First_Name>John</First_Name>
  <Last_Name>Thomas</Last_Name>
  <Address>Stuttgart</Address>
</record>
<record>
  <First_Name>Aanshi</First_Name>
  <Last_Name></Last_Name>
  <Address>Stuttgart</Address>
</record>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an XSLT problem, not a Windows versus Linux, CRLF versus LF problem? It looks like the second to me. Does [this link help](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/720626-controlling-eol-convention-xslt-output)?

Comment: @torazaburo: Yes, you are right. I have updated it.

Comment: What do you mean by `remove space between two line`? What space?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin:I have updated question .

Comment: Huh? You are asking for html-style open and close tags for empty elements in the output (as per `Address` example), but then you contradict yourself, by showing that you want a self-closed tag for the empty `Last_name` element.

Comment: @kreya Are you sure that's the **exact** output you're getting? With the indents? I have heard of this problem of extra lines before, in conjunction with Filemaker on Windows - but then you would have no indents in your output.

Answer (score 0):

A simple work-around to avoiding self-closing tags is to insert a comment:

```
<Address><xsl:value-of select="dso:Address"/><xsl:comment/></Address>
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That will insert an empty comment in the output, but that shouldn't hurt anything.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887739/xslt-self-closing-tags-issue).

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Do you know how to remove space between nodes/lines ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a filemaker bug. The OP should add a `filemaker` tag. I took some reading in http://filemakerhacks.com/2012/09/23/export-field-contents-as-utf-8/ and found in one of the comments by Ben Kreunen

"*I had a similar issue recently with the extra blank lines and eventually came up with a twist on an XSLT file. The particular fix was to turn off indenting in the output method.*"

Have you tried setting the output indent to "no"?

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
```

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this problem? If so, which processor, on which platform?

Comment: I did not notice the filemaker namespace there, sorry.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen: Thanks for the reply. I set the indent to "no". But it produce same output.